# Can we have a single portlet instance on multiple pages in liferay?

Tags: instance, portlet, liferay

Can we have a single portlet instance on multiple pages in liferay?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your portlet dropped in several pages but have only one set of data and configuration, make sure your liferay-portlet.xml has

```
instanceable=false
preferences-unique-per-layout=false
```

and if you want the community administrator to be the only one allowed to change the preferences, add

```
preferences-owned-by-group=true
```